# Past simple and continuous time

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

My teacher told me that when I just want to state a fact and I don't intend to make any store then I'm only allowed to use the past simple and not the past continuous
For instance

I worked there for three months

I was working there for three months

Is that true or both versions are correct when I just state a fact what I did for three months?

Comment: Like many general rules, they apply sometimes and not always. Both versions make sense by themselves.

Comment: Both sound natural by themsleves?

Comment: The second (continuous) version is unlikely except in contexts where you're also talking about *other* things that happened in the past, such as *I was working there for three months **when the hurricane hit.*** But when in doubt, *always* use simple verb tenses.

Comment: Thank you.......

Comment: Hm, there's a difference between "not allowed to"/"correct" vs "not likely to"/"odd". It's not a rule.

Comment: The past continuous tens makes perfect sense in a reply, e.g., "How long had you worked for that company before that issue?" "I was working there for three months." (Or, "I had worked there for three months." to indicate interruption.)

Comment: Also: “I was working there for three months and at their competitor for six.”

Answer (score 0):

"I worked here for three months" - You worked there for 3 months but no longer work at that company anymore

"I was working there for three months" - You worked there for 3 months and still working for that company now

Comment: No, this is not the meaning of "was working".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).